# Adding Content-Disposition header in Python - email isn't sent

Tags: python, email

Following the directions in [Python's email examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) and in several Stack Overflow questions, I wrote the following function (sending through the Gmail SMTP server):

```
def send_email(emailaddr, message, attachmentfile = None, subject = None):
   try:
        smtpconn = smtplib.SMTP(mainconf["SMTPHOST"], mainconf["SMTPPORT"])
        smtpconn.set_debuglevel(1)
        smtpconn.ehlo()
        smtpconn.starttls()
        smtpconn.login(mainconf["SMTPUSER"], mainconf["SMTPPASS"])
        if not attachmentfile:
           message = '\n' + message
           smtpconn.sendmail(mainconf["EMAILFROM"], emailaddr, message)
        else:
           multipart = MIMEMultipart()
           multipart['Subject'] = subject if subject else "Attachment"
           multipart['From'] = mainconf["EMAILFROM"]  
           multipart['To'] = emailaddr
           with open(attachmentfile, 'rb') as fp:
               filepart = MIMEApplication(fp.read())
           multipart.attach(filepart)
           multipart.attach(message)
           smtpconn.sendmail(mainconf["EMAILFROM"], emailaddr, multipart.as_string())
        generallog.info("Sent an email to {0}".format(emailaddr))
   except:
        generallog.warn("Email sending to {0} failed with error message {1}".format(emailaddr, traceback.format_exception_only(sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

This works fine for sending an email with an attachment, but it results in the famous [noname problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831788/email-attachment-received-as-noname) (that's just one of several SO questions on the subject).  So I add in this:

```
  filepart.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=os.basename(attachmentfile))
```

Then Gmail simply refuses to send the email.  When I run this code in the Python shell, I get the standard `message accepted` message, but the message is never delivered.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Where do you add that? What is filepart?

Comment: filepart is the MIMEApplication object - see the with statement. I added it just before the multipart.attach command.